# online reflector without install

Tags: reflector, .net-reflector

I am looking for a refelector to see the code inside dll, I have a restriction that I can not install the software in the system. Is there any reflector exists which is either online or doesn't require to get installed first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to actually install reflector.   I will often run it a usb drive.   You can simply copy the files to the computer and run it.   Delete the files when you are through.